# ODEs with sine and cosine

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When we are solving ODEs with sine and cosine, we often simplify the equation using Eula's equation.For example, for the equation $\frac{dy}{dx}+y=\sin x$, we first solve the equation $\frac{dy}{dx}+y=e^{ix}$, where we take $i$ as a constant number.With the solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}+y=e^{ix}$, we get the imaginary part of the solution as our "real" solution.
During this process, I have a question.
.Why can we do this?A crude thought is that it is based on complex number theory.But as a beginner in calculus, I do not have the ability to learn it by myself.
I want to know the answer is because I want to know the range that this method can be applied.And in my circuit analysis class, I am already facing the same questions.

Comment: It is Leonhard Euler. An EULA is some kind of automatic contract.

Comment: Yes, you are right @LutzLehmann .I apologize for the mistake

Answer (score 2):

There are several things going here:

**Euler identity for complex number**

We have $e^{ix}=\cos{(x)}+i\sin{(x)}$, so the second equation is equal to the following:

$$
\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}y+y=\cos{(x)}+i\sin{(x)}
$$

**Linearity of the differential equation**

The ODE is linear so the solution to the aforementioned equation can be decomposed into two parts: $y(x)=y_{1}(x)+y_{2}(x)$ where

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}y_{1}+y_{1}&=\cos{(x)} \\
\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}y_{2}+y_{2}&=i\sin{(x)}
\end{aligned}
$$

In addition, $y_{2}=iy_{3}$ where

$$
\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}y_{3}+y_{3}=\sin{(x)}
$$

**Zero phase - shift**

The solution of each differential equation has the same phase as the force on the right hand side. This is because second derivative of sine is also a sine and cosine will also remain cosine. Consequently, $y_{1}$ will only have cosine and $y_{2}$ will only have sine. In other words, the solution due to $\cos{(x)}$ will not interfere with the solution due to $\sin{(x)}$.

This will not be possible if you have first derivative in your differential equation. So that's already one of the limitation of this approach.

**Remark**

I think this is not the proper way to teach differential equations or circuit analysis. Typical "if this very particular condition is valid then you can use this shortcut formula" approach that engineering professors usually use.

Either the lecture was not delivered appropriately or the lecturer does not know what he/she's doing.

Answer (score 0):

In linear DE with forcing terms you can separately solve for each right-side term and after that combine the solutions to get a particular solution for the original equation. So if you have $L[y]=r_1+r_2+r_3$ and solve $L[y_k]=r_k$, then $y_p=y_1+y_2+y_3$.

Here if you solve $L[y_1]=e^{ix}$, then you have also automatically found $y_2=\bar y_1$ as solution for $L[y_2]=e^{-ix}$. Then
$$
L[y_1-y_2]=e^{ix}-e^{-ix}=2i\sin(x)
$$
and so also with $y_p=Im(y_1)=\frac{y_1-y_2}{2i}$
$$
L[y_p]=\sin(x).
$$

This idea of manipulating the right-side terms (of linear DE with constant coefficients) is more-or-less formalized, generalized and tabulated in the Laplace transform calculus, which is a reason why it is so wide-spread in engineering.

---

As to the added question, the reason that this works is that the real differential commutes with the complex structure as whole, not just multiplication with complex constants, but also the conjugation, thus real and imaginary parts (as operations).

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the answer is that differentiation is a linear operator, which means that $\frac{d}{dx}(a y_1(x) + b y_2(x)) = a \frac{d}{dx} y_1(x) + b \frac{d}{dx} y_2(x)$.

So that means that given a DE such as $\frac{dy}{dx} + y = \sin x$ we can define a new function $u(x) = y_1(x) + i y_2(x)$ such that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are both real-valued functions. Then if we construct a new DE:

$\frac{du}{dx} + u = e^{ix}$

we can look at our decomposition, along with Euler's formula for $e^{ix}$ and see that we get:

$\begin{eqnarray}\frac{d}{dx} (y_1 + i y_2) + (y_1 + i y_2) & = & \cos x + i \sin x \\
\frac{d y_1}{dx} + i \frac{d y_2}{dx} + y_1 + i y_2 & = & \cos x + i \sin x \\
\left(\frac{d y_1}{dx} + y_1 \right) + i \left(\frac{d y_2}{dx} + y_2 \right) & = & \cos x + i \sin x\end{eqnarray}$

Then, noting that two complex numbers are equal if and only if both their real and imaginary parts are equal, this means that we now have two separate DEs over the real numbers (since the derivative of a real-valued function is also real), namely $\frac{d y_1}{dx} + y_1 = \cos x$ and $\frac{d y_2}{dx} + y_2 = \sin x$. And, as luck would have it, that second DE is exactly the one we were trying to solve. So that means that if we solve the complex DE for $u$, then the imaginary part of $u$ must be a solution to our DE. With a bit of messing around, you can show that existence and uniqueness theorems translate between these DEs in some fashion.

This method only works in this fashion when your DEs are linear, meaning they are of the form:

$a_n(x) \frac{d^n y}{dx^n} + \ldots + a_1(x) \frac{dy}{dx} + a_0(x) y = b(x)$

The linearity of the DE, combined with the linearity of the differential operators, is what lets everything decompose as required. If you had a non-linear DE, such as $yy' = f(x)$, you'll find that the decomposition is nowhere near as pretty.